# Woocommerce: How to display product price

Tags: loop, woocommerce-offtopic

I created a loop that should show the image, the name/title and the price of the product. I managed successfully to show the image and the name/title, but not the price. My knowledge of PHP is not good, but I would like to understand where I am wrong. This is my current code:

```
<?php
        foreach ($category_slugs as $category_slug){
            $products = woo_site_builder_get_products_by_category($category_slug);

            if($products):
                echo "<ul id='$category_slug'>";
                foreach ($products as $product):
                    $product_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($product->get_id()));
                    if(!$product_image) continue;
                    echo '<li class="structural-elements" data-category="'.$category_slug.'" data-productid="'.$product->get_id().'"><span>'.get_the_title($product->get_id()).'</span><span class="price_section">'.get_price($product->get_id()).'</span><img src="'.$product_image.'"></li>';
                endforeach;
                echo "</ul>";
            endif;
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `$product->get_price()` take a look at `WooCommerce` `WC_Product` class.